# Unable to connect to FCM

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have followed google sample project to implement notification in iOS, However my app is crashing on following line,

```
[[FIRMessaging messaging] connectWithCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error)
```

The whole function is here to connect with Firebase Cloud Messaging(FCM),

```
 - (void)connectToFcm {
  [[FIRMessaging messaging] connectWithCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error != nil) 
    {
      NSLog(@"Unable to connect to FCM. %@", error);
    } 
    else 
    {
      NSLog(@"Connected to FCM.");
    }
  }];
}
```

Error: **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSData gtm_dataByGzippingData:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10fd1f110'**

Please help me! How can I solve this?

Comment: It looks like a category is not loaded. Do you have the "-ObjC" switch in "Other linker flags" set in your build settings ? How did you install the library ?

Comment: @SamuelPeter In my project, "Other linker flags" set to "lc++". When I add new flag "-ObjC", It is generating linker error. I have use cocoa pods to install Firebase library. Is there any other solutions? Thanks!

Comment: I am not a user of this library myself, but just for checking I cloned this example app : https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/tree/master/messaging. I ran `pod install`, then opened the .xcworkspace and saw that Cocoapods had indeed added -ObjC to the Other Linker Flags of the project, along with quite a few libraries besides just the c++ standard lib. I think you might have installed the library wrong. What are the contents of your Podfile ?

Comment: @SamuelPeter Thank you for your answer! 
pode file is as below,
`
target 'Product Listing' do
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
end
`

Comment: @SagarUnagar I am getting same error in my app. did you find any solution for that? if yes than please help me to solve this.

Comment: @SagarUnagar ur prob got resolved or u need answer. let us know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to Build Settings

find 'Other Linker Flags'

add '-ObjC'

this will fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

check your platform version in your pod file

it will be like "*platform :ios, '8.0'*"

update the version to 9.0 and then run command pod install

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'
target 'Product Listing' do
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
end
```